# How to reset cycle counter?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have in template this:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% ifchanged item.st2 %}
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="item-title">{{ item.get_st2 }}</div>
    {% endifchanged %}
    <div class="cell {% cycle 'clear tco1' 'tco' 'tco' 'tco2' 'clear tce1' 'tce' 'tce' 'tce2' %}">{{ item.name }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

and it shows things like this:

```
------------------ st2 name 1 -------------------

+-----------------------------------------------+
| grey item | grey item | grey item | grey item |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| dark item | dark item | dark item | dark item |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| grey item | grey item | grey item | grey item |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| dark item | dark item | dark item | dark item |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| grey item | grey item | grey item | grey item |
+-----------------------------------------------+

------------------ st2 name 2 -------------------

+-----------------------------------------------+
| grey item | grey item | grey item | grey item |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| dark item | dark item | dark item | dark item |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

and its good.

But if items on st2 name is less than 4 in one line:

```
------------------ st2 name 1 -------------------

+-----------------------------------------------+
| grey item | grey item | grey item | grey item |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| dark item | dark item | dark item |
+-----------------------------------+
```

then next looks like this:

```
------------------ st2 name 1 -------------------

+-----------------------------------+
| grey item | grey item | grey item | 
+-----------------------------------------------+
| dark item | dark item | dark item | dark item |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

because cycle coutner is still on the fourth element.

How to reset cycle tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cycle` tag with `silent` keyword to declare the cycle but not produce the first value. By giving the cycle tag a name, using `"as"` you can insert the current value of the cycle wherever you’d like. Another `cycle` tag with name of the variable will move cycle to the next value independently. And `divisibleby` tag can be used to check for last in line item:

```
{% cycle 'clear tco1' 'tco' 'tco' 'tco2' 'clear tce1' 'tce' 'tce' 'tce2' as cellcls silent %}
{% for item in items %}
    {% ifchanged item.st2 %}
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="item-title">{{ item.get_st2 }}</div>
        {% if not forloop.counter1|divisibleby:"4" %}  {# im not tested it #}
            {% cycle cellcls %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endifchanged %}
    <div class="cell {{cellcls}}">{{ item.name }}</div>
    {% cycle cellcls %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, but it works:

```
{% cycle '1' '2' '3' '4' as cellcount silent %}
{% cycle 'tco1' 'tco' 'tco' 'tco2' 'tce1' 'tce' 'tce' 'tce2' as cellcls silent %}
{% for item in items %}
    {% ifchanged item.st2 %}
        {% if not forloop.first %}
            {% if cellcount|add:0 == 2 %}
                {% cycle cellcls %}{% cycle cellcls %}{% cycle cellcls %}
                {% cycle cellcount %}{% cycle cellcount %}{% cycle cellcount %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if cellcount|add:0 == 3 %}
                {% cycle cellcls %}{% cycle cellcls %}
                {% cycle cellcount %}{% cycle cellcount %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if cellcount|add:0 == 4 %}
                {% cycle cellcls %}
                {% cycle cellcount %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="item-title">{{ item.get_st2 }}</div>
    {% endifchanged %}
    <div class="cell {{ cellcls }}" style="{{ cellcount }}">{{ item.name }}</div>
    {% cycle cellcls %}
    {% cycle cellcount %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across same problem and write small custom template tag (works in django 1.8):

```
from django import template
import itertools


register = template.Library()


class ResetCycleNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, variable_name, cycle_node):
        self.variable_name = variable_name
        self.cycle_node = cycle_node

    def render(self, context):
        cycle_iter = itertools.cycle(self.cycle_node.cyclevars)
        context.render_context[self.cycle_node] = cycle_iter
        context[self.variable_name] = next(cycle_iter).resolve(context)
        return ''


@register.tag
def reset_cycle(parser, token, escape=False):
    args = token.split_contents()

    if len(args) != 2:
        raise TemplateSyntaxError("'reset_cycle' tag requires exactly one argument")

    name = args[1]
    if not hasattr(parser, '_namedCycleNodes'):
        raise TemplateSyntaxError("No named cycles in template. '%s' is not defined" % name)
    if name not in parser._namedCycleNodes:
        raise TemplateSyntaxError("Named cycle '%s' does not exist" % name)

    return ResetCycleNode(name, parser._namedCycleNodes[name])
```

And then use it in template like this:

```
{% cycle 'clear tco1' 'tco' 'tco' 'tco2' 'clear tce1' 'tce' 'tce' 'tce2' as cellclass silent %}
{% for item in items %}
    {% ifchanged item.st2 %}
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="item-title">{{ item.get_st2 }}</div>
        {% reset_cycle cellclass %}
    {% endifchanged %}
    <div class="cell {{ cellclass }}{% cycle cellclass %}">{{ item.name }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but as of Django 1.11 there is a built-in tag, [`resetcycle`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#resetcycle) that appears to do what OP wants.